# req() on output$Var in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

In the simple example below I create some output in `output$something` that takes some time to run. I want to create an `req()` for a later process that executes only when `output$something` exists.

The code below comments out the part that I'm trying to figure out because it otherwise breaks the app. Is it possible to use `req(output$something)` in some way as I'm tring to do below such that later things happen only when this output exists?

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- fluidPage(

    navbarPage(
        theme = bs_theme(bootswatch = "flatly", version = 4),
        title = 'Methods',
        tabPanel('One'),
    ),
    mainPanel(
        h1('Hello World'),      
        
     verbatimTextOutput("something"),
    br()
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$something <- renderPrint({
        Sys.sleep(5) #simulate some process happening 
        'Test'
    })
    
    #output$newThing({
    #   req(output$something)
    # Do other stuff
    #})

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use it with `observeEvent`:

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  navbarPage(
    theme = bs_theme(bootswatch = "flatly", version = 4),
    title = 'Methods',
    tabPanel('One'),
  ),
  mainPanel(
    h1('Hello World'),      
    
    verbatimTextOutput("something"),
    br()
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$something <- renderPrint({
    Sys.sleep(1) #simulate some process happening 
    'Test'
  })
  
  observeEvent(outputOptions(output, "something"),{
    print('Do other stuff')
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```